# english number and ltr direction in xetex

Tags: xetex, amsmath, xepersian

I'm writing a document using xepersian and the text direction is right to left. Also I need to add formulas in the document. My problem is that all numbers in the formula are persian and if I add text in the formula it will be in the wrong order.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
\begin{align*}
    Q_{n,0}&=1
    \quad Q_{0,k}=[k=0]; \\
    Q_{n,k}&=Q_{n-1,k}+Q_{n-1,k-1}+\binom{n}{k}, \quad\text{for$n,k>$0.}
\end{align*}
```

In this example all 1's and 0's are persian and the text in the fromula is in the revers order.
How do I fix it?

EDIT:

This is a sample doc that has the same problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    Q_{n,0}&=1
    \quad Q_{0,k}=[k=0]; \\
    Q_{n,k}&=Q_{n-1,k}+Q_{n-1,k-1}+\binom{n}{k}, \quad\text{for$n,k>$0.}
\end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I edited and added a sample code

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean, but `\text` keeps the main writing direction, which is right-to-left in your case; does `\text{\LR{for $n,k>0$.}` help? Also add `\DefaultMathsDigits` before `\begin{document}` if you want digits in math to be the Western ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\text` uses the writing direction that was current when the formula in which it appears started. According to the documentation of `xepersian` you can use `\lr`. For getting digits in math mode using Western glyphs, issue the `\DefaultMathsDigits` command in the preamble.

Here's the minimal example (I commented the font selection lines because I don't have that font):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
%\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}
\DefaultMathsDigits


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    Q_{n,0}&=1
    \quad Q_{0,k}=[k=0]; \\
    Q_{n,k}&=Q_{n-1,k}+Q_{n-1,k-1}+\binom{n}{k}, \quad\text{\lr{for $n,k>0$.}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Notice that `0` should be *inside* the inner formula.

[image]